# Shade Tolerant Strawberry Varieties?

Tags: strawberries

I would like to plant strawberries at the East end of my house in an existing bed. (I live in zone 5b) I've been trying to find an ever bearing variety that will do ok in partial shade but so far haven't found any.

Does anybody know of any tips or techniques to get standard strawberries to produce in partial shade or a variety they've had success with in a shady area?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind alpine strawberries, [Alexandria](https://www.rareseeds.com/alexandria-a-strawberry/) seems to do quite well in partial shade, especially on its second year. I grew it from seed last year. They're very small fruits, though. The plants look really nice.

They seem to fruit over a longer season than other strawberries in my area. I mean, they've started fruiting in early May, and last year I they were still fruiting after the last frost.

Although they can fruit the first year, don't expect to have much more than a little snack now and then, the first year. I'm waiting to see how they do this year, but they're looking more prolific, and the plants are a lot bigger and nicer.

They don't produce runners, typically. People usually grow them from seed.

I tried [Yellow Wonder](https://www.rareseeds.com/yellow-wonder-wild-strawberry/), too, which is similar, except it's yellow, and didn't sprout as many plants from the seeds I planted. We got more fruit from Alexandria, though, but maybe that's just because of the number of plants.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience! I was hoping to avoid small berried varieties, based on your experience I may try a few and see how they perform in my situation.

Comment: @CSharpQuestions I have some shaded by the eves on the northern side of our house, and after they had been there for a year or two, this year they started getting much larger fruits! They're bigger than those from plants with more sun. I highly recommend alpine strawberries, since they produce year to year, without having to replace the plants. If you plant them somewhere up high, it should make harvesting easier.